# iPhone simulator for iPod Touch 4G

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, nstimer, ipod-touch

What would be the equivalent version of the iPhone simulator for iPod Touch 4G in xcode?

I am trying to simulate an app that I have on the app-store for close to a year now.  Recently, a new user complained that the app crashed on its iPod Touch 4G with IOS 6.0.1.  I decided to start the debug with the simulator.  But I am not sure which version of iPhone simulator I should use for the iPod 4G.  Is it iPhone 5?

BTW, it is a pretty simple app which does not use any hardware features that are not available on iPod Touch 2G.  We tested the app on iPod Touch 2G at the time of release as a minimum hardware required.  It does use NSTimers and the users complain seems to revolve around it.

I appreciate any help.

Thank you.
Best regards,

Comment: Use the 3.5" retina iPhone simulator. Get the crash report from the user.

Comment: Look for other differences (iOS version, jailbroken or not, privacy settings, etc.). It's not very common that a less powerful device runs an app better than a more powerful one.

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent for iPod Touch 4G would be and iPhone Simulator with 3.5 inch screen size and retina display. 
`When you launch the simulator, in the menu bar select: Hardware -> Device -> iPhone (Retina 3.5 inch)`
The version of the iOS may vary and you can change it from the `Hardware -> Version` menu. To instal simulators with previous iOS versions go to `Xcode -> Preferences -> Downloads`

Comment: Thx.  Just wondering does apple keep a list somewhere that shows us the compatibility of the simulator with the iPod devices?

Answer (score -1):

As you said, your application is in app store for almost a year. It should work fine in higher iOS version such as 6.0 and above. But I faced same problem for some UI . Which works fine in 5.0 but fails in 6.0. May be some methods are deprecated.

Make sure you get the perfect logs. Try iPhone 6.0 simulator